# Why is it giving an Uncaught Type Error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, google-apps-script

Could you please help to understand why it is giving an Uncaught Type Error? In the code there is no typo in the function names, and no function being called on the wrong object.
Here is the [link](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwEsHmPUxZwOr28AWoonjURrM7BEcNQnjP9a3SfJ6bvGX6F182K/exec) to the working app.

Here is the [`link`](https://pastebin.com/YXvyCU0p) to the code.

In the console, the error is (please note the error starts in about one minute after the page is launched:
Uncaught TypeError: b is not a function

When I drill in into the error in the debugger, it shows:
[image]

Comment: i think it should be `B()` instead of `b()` as i can see `var a=B()`

Comment: Where you define `b = Na` , what is `Na`?

Comment: That is the thing i don't understand this part, because that error snippet is not in my code at all. That error snippet is showing in the console when i drill into the details of the error that says: Uncaught TypeError: b is not a function

Comment: That error snippet is showing in the console when i drill into the details of the error that says: Uncaught TypeError: b is not a function